# What function is invoked when user clicks on "add to cart"?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

I would like to modify the add to cart function (cookies and sessions in order to fix a problem) but I don't know where is that function located. Can someone please tell me where can I find the the file, with function, that is called on click of that button? Also, what function is called? I need to get to the function that creates the cookies/session and modify it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the methods responsible for adding an item to the cart is called [`WC_Cart::add_to_cart()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#894).

You should **not** edit that file directly because:

1. Future updates to the plugin will override your changes;
2. WooCommerce code (and associated plugins) can be *very* complicated behind the scenes, especially when using additional plugins; and
3. WordPress and WooCommerce provide ample hooks for you to override default functionality.

#### Using WooCommerce Hooks

WooCommerce provides plenty of [hooks](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/) that will allow you to override the default functionality. Without knowing your exact goals, it's hard to specify which hook should be used, but there are a few possible options:

1. [`woocommerce_add_to_cart`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#991)
2. [`woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_AJAX.html#435)
3. [`woocommerce_cart_updated`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#286)
4. [`woocommerce_set_cart_cookies`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#193)

A full list of hooks is available in the [WooCommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html).

#### Example of WooCommerce Hook

The following function will set a cookie after the cart has been updated.

```
function setCartCookie()
{
    $_COOKIE['foo'] = 'bar';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_updated', 'setCartCookie' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything or at least most of it, related to the cart, in file includes/class-wc-cart.php

WooCommerce uses the WordPress Plugin API to enhance everything, so you can hook a function when an item has been added to the cart and change it without needing to modify the function that creates the cookie.

The method that sets an item to cart is:

```
add_to_cart()
```

The method in that class to set cookies is:

```
set_cart_cookies()
```

and for the session is:

```
set_session()
```

Some of the action hooks you can use to hook on it and change what you need to change are:

```
'woocommerce_cart_updated' -> cart has been updated on session
'woocommerce_set_cart_cookies' -> cookies are set
'woocommerce_add_to_cart' -> item added to cart
```

If you are tweaking cookies/sessions be sure to test everything so that the change you have made does not break a part of the WooCommerce